# fmincon with nonzero inequalities constraint

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, inequalities

I want to solve a minimization problem in MATLAB.

[`fmincon()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html):

> `x = fmincon(fun,x0,Aeq,beq, nonlcon)` subjects  to the nonlinear inequalities c(x)  defined in `nonlcon` such that c(x) < 0

Is it possible to change c(x) < 0 to c(x) ≤ 0 and use `fmincon()` function? Does it have any effect on my obtained results? I tried `fmincon` and obtained the reasonable results but I do not know the effect of this change in my results? which function do you suggest to use in MATLAB for this problem?

Comment: see the help of `fmincon`https://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html, c(x) should be <= 0

Comment: Relook at the documentation for [`fmincon()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html):  "`x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon)` subjects the minimization to the nonlinear inequalities c(x) or equalities ceq(x) defined in `nonlcon`. `fmincon` optimizes such that c(x) ≤ 0 and ceq(x) = 0. If no bounds exist, set lb = [] and/or ub = []."  Inequalities are not strict for `fmincon`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be noted that, strictly speaking, the constraint c(x) < 0 is a subset of c(x)<=0, so your result of optimization should be a solution with relaxed condition when with c(x)<=0.

Considering the numeric calculation by MATLAB, the impact might be tiny since you also have calculation precision issues, so no need to worry about it.